# Problem with ADO query connection to a DB Grid in Delphi?

Tags: sql, ms-access, delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

**Problem background:**
So I'm trying to display a table (the specific table gets selected in a radio group in my GUI) from my database normally in a DBGrid so that when a user types in a SQL query they would be able to see the changes in the table in the DBGrid.
***(All images shown are from Delphi's design view unless otherwise stated)***

Image of radio group where you can select a table (the radio group doesn't do anything yet):

[image]

**The main problem:**
The problem is it doesn't display everything, it only displays the first column on the DBGrid and nothing else.

Example of the output I'm talking about:
[image]

**Extra info regarding the form, components, etc:**
The data source connected to my DBGrid declared as a TDataSource component is called dsrSQL. I'm using a TADOQuery component called qrySQL which is connected to conClientInfo (a TADOConnection component that connects to the database). That data source has qrySQL as it's DataSet. All of the components are active and enabled. They are also all in one single data module called DM_client_u. (I did declare the data module under uses in my form's code)

Image of one of the tables in Access:
[image]

**What I tried:**
I redid the connection string in conClientInfo, checked the qrySQL component and the DBGrid. I still don't see any problems on the surface of the program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your real problem is the width of the first column. The rest of the data is there, but you have to scroll horizontally to see it. If you haven't explicitly defined the width of the first column or you use implicit columns, the width is calculated automatically according to underlying field's data type and DBGrid's font. For big VARCHAR fields it can be a huge number.

Comment: @PeterWolf Thanks , changing the width of the columns helped a lot! But some of my fields are having WIDEMEMO values? How could I solve that problem? (I changed the data types of my fields in Access, all to short text instead of long text as well)

Comment: Frankly, imo you need to re-think your q, because most of the info in it is irrelevant, e.g. an image of a non-functional radio group, which it is utterly pointless to show and an image of what a table looks like in Access.  The details you should include are the field types and sizes in the tables (stated in text, not images) and the code you are using to open the tables and how you are resetting the DBGrid when you switch tables.  It isn't a good idea to try and use the same grid to disply data from differently-structured tables unless you know how to make this work with a DBGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind me saying so, you are creating problems for yourself by trying to use the same DBGrid to
display data from 2 tables with different structures, when you don't know how to do it.
In any case, trying to do it means you lose the ability to set up the grid's appearance at design time
and adapt it to suit the particular data from each table.

Here's what I suggest you do instead:

1. Add a TPageControl to your form and  add two TTabSheets to it.
2. Put a TDataSource, TDBGrid and TDBNavigator on each TTabSheet, and connect each TDataSource to
   one of the datasets in your datamodule.   Assuming the AdoQueries involved already have Sql suited
   to retrieve the data you wish to display, set both AdoQueries to active and use the Columns editor
   (which you can access by right-clicking each TDBGrid) to set up and size the grid Columns for each
   field.
3. Now you can control the display of each AdoQuery independently without tying yoursself in knots.

If using a TPageControl is not to your taste, do something like embedding each TDBGrid it its own TPanel,
make the two TPanels occupy the exact same area on your form and use code to display one of the panels
or the other depending on the setting of your TRadioGroup, by setting one TPanel's Visible property to
True and the other to False.

Btw, once you've got the 2 TDBGrids looking and working as you want, set the
AdoQueries to Active = False and use code to open them at run-time - it's bad practice
to leave things like DB connections and DataSets active at design time.  You'll
find out why when you get an unexpected problem, e.g. when you are expecting your app to have exclusive access to the tables, as when attempting to restructure them ar run-time.

Comment: Ok, I'll make good use of your advice. I just have 1 more question though. How do you add TTabSheets to a TPageControl? Because I don't see a separate component for TTabSheet, do you have to add code in the handler for the page control or..?

Comment: Right-click the PageControl and select New Page from the pop-up menu (twice).